# Can't get aligned right nav items with Bootstrap 4 to appear in responsive view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Bootstrap, so please allow me the probably simple question. 
I'm trying to create a navbar with bootstrap 4, with the majority of menu items on the left, but with the login button on the right. I've figured some roundabout way of doing it (which could be wrong) but whenever I view the page in phone or tablet view, the 'login' item of the menu doesn't appear when one clicks the burger menu icon. 
It appears up to a point (think it's about 760px) and then just disappears from view.
Here's the markup to this point, any help at all would be appreciated.

```
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="imgs/branding/nerve logo_small.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 3</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul> 
            </div>
           <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex"> 
                <li class="nav-item text-right">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is here

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex"> 
                <li class="nav-item text-right">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**d-none d-md-flex** - this part means, that this element will be hidden (d-none) until 768px (d-**md**-flex), and then will be displayed as flex. Try to remove **d-none**

**UPDATED**

The best way is to remove a standalone login ul and add Login as a part of a global ul list.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Placeholder 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item flex-sm-grow-1 text-sm-right">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Look closer to **flex-sm-grow-1 text-sm-right** in Login li. And don't forget to add **w-100** to ul.

Comment: This does work thanks! When I remove d-none, 'login' will stay in place however whilst the rest of the menu turns into burger style. Is there any way to get it all to collapse at the same time whilst keeping login on the far right?

Comment: Can you add an open tag <nav> to you example? I need little more info to figure it out right.

Comment: I figured it out thanks! I added `<ul class="navbar-nav flex-row d-none d-lg-block ml-md-auto"> ` to the 'login' part, and added another login to the above div that is only visible on screens smaller than lg which menas it's hidden when full menu visible!

Comment: Updated the answer. Found the perfect solution for you, without duplicating Login.

Comment: This is absolutely spot on, just what I was looking for and keeps the markup clean - thanks so much for your help!